# Use shared_ptr of unsigned char array in SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig, shared-ptr

I'm using SWIG to make C++ code available in C#.
One of the tasks is to exchange data via `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>`
representing an array of unsigned chars. The size is given separately.
I think a suitable representation in C# would be as `byte[]`.

Unfortunately I was not able to manage this "translation". Here is an examplary SWIG interface file:

```
%module example
%include <stdint.i>
%include <std_pair.i>
%include <std_shared_ptr.i>
%include <arrays_csharp.i>

// would result in compile error: "error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'unsigned char *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
//%apply unsigned char INPUT[]  {std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>}
//%apply unsigned char OUTPUT[] {std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>}

%apply unsigned char INPUT[]  {unsigned char*}
%apply unsigned char OUTPUT[] {unsigned char*}

%apply unsigned int {std::size_t}

%template (MyDataPair) std::pair<std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>, std::size_t>;

%inline %{
#include <memory>

typedef std::pair<std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>,std::size_t> MyDataPair;

struct MyDataStruct
{
    std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data;
    std::size_t size;

    MyDataStruct(std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> p_data, std::size_t p_size) : data(p_data), size(p_size) {}
};

void setDataWithPointer(unsigned char* p_data, std::size_t p_size);

void setDataWithSharedPointer(std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> p_data, std::size_t p_size);

std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> getDataOfPair(const MyDataPair p_data) {
    return p_data.first;
}

std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> getDataOfStruct(const MyDataStruct p_data) {
    return p_data.data;
}

%}
```

The output looks like this (generated in example.cs):

```
public class example {
  public static void setDataWithPointer(byte[] p_data, uint p_size) {
    examplePINVOKE.setDataWithPointer(p_data, p_size);
  }

  public static void setDataWithSharedPointer(SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t p_data, uint p_size) {
    examplePINVOKE.setDataWithSharedPointer(SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t.getCPtr(p_data), p_size);
    if (examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
  }

  public static SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t getDataOfPair(MyDataPair p_data) {
    SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t ret = new SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t(examplePINVOKE.getDataOfPair(MyDataPair.getCPtr(p_data)), true);
    if (examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }

  public static SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t getDataOfStruct(MyDataStruct p_data) {
    SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t ret = new SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t(examplePINVOKE.getDataOfStruct(MyDataStruct.getCPtr(p_data)), true);
    if (examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Pending) throw examplePINVOKE.SWIGPendingException.Retrieve();
    return ret;
  }

}
```

Only the first method, using a raw pointer, has `byte[]` in its signature, for the rest the type `SWIGTYPE_p_std__shared_ptrT_unsigned_char_t` is used, which cannot be used in a practical way (or can it? as far as I understand it can only be passed around, but not "really" used).

Has someone dealt with that or a similar problem before? Is this something for self-defined typemaps?